# HTML JQuery Javascript saving user information after login?

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

I been designing websites for a while now, but I've never actually created a log-in-based website, before. I have a website designed that stores and retrieves data from a database, including user log-in information.

After a user has entered the correct log-in information, how do you store the logged-in state, and the users data to use when they, for instance, click on their profile? I'm assuming cookies, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What server-sided language are you using? Users can manipulate local storage information.

Comment: you use sessions, which is basically a way to use cookies smartly. What language are you using on the server-side?

Comment: I recently switched from MySQL to using Firebase, so I'm using Javascript to push/retrieve data from my database. I'm using PHP to handle most everything else on the site.

Comment: Then use `$_SESSION["user"]` (for PHP). In which you can place the users ID, or whatever identifies a user.